# Как/где лучше оформить/сделать помощь по сайту

Tags: фреймворк, php, html, kohana

Доброе время суток, форумчане.

Сделал сайт (с ипользованием kohana), и вот думаю, как правильно (лучше) оформить помощь по сайту?
Т.е. **своеобразную инструкцию** по пользованию сайтом (выводящуюся *интернет браузером*).
А именно сам текст помощи/инструкции, должен быть в **БД** (и потом ее подкачивать, при выборе определенного раздела "помощи"), или просто сделать/оформить несколько сот страничек в виде **html** (по конкретным темам помощи/инструкции)?

Comment: @Konstantin78, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: просто к созданному сайту-документообороту, нужно сделать обычную инструкцию пользователя

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с таким понятием, как [юзабилити](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8). Если использование сайта требует ещё и инструкции к нему...

Answer (score 1):

Как обычно, инструкции никто не читает. Это норма(с). При этом многие решения даже не то чтобы неочевидны, просто никто не знает, что так можно. Поэтому имеет смысл поступать как во флеш-игрушках и некоторых современных сайтах: помощь интегрирована в те разделы, где она больше всего нужна.
Пользователь на странице с кучей инфы? Подскажите ему удобную кнопку сортировки, что можно воспользоваться фильтром/распределить инфу по папкам.
Пользователь зарегался, но не понимает нафига заполнять все поля профиля? Расскажите о преимуществах.
Пользователь Пару раз промахнулся с паролем? Расскажите ему как можно вернуть доступ к сайту.
И так далее. Отдельный раздел с помощью будет простаивать.

Comment: Согласен, но это на тех многих сайтах, на которых, конкретный результат не очень важен, и на которые заходят посторонние (чужие) люди.   
В моем документообороте, важным будет каждый результат, т.к. это работа сотрудников (не будет конкретного результата от них - будут гулять). 
Во-вторых документооборот, для ограниченного числа людей (не посторонних), так что лишние примочки там ни к чему, да потом превратятся в назойливость. (согласен, кое-где можно повесить хинты, но это и все)/       
*Да и все-таки, так где- же правильней хранить инструкцию в **БД** или **html**?/

Comment: @Konstantin78
> ...конкретный результат не очень важен.

Вы ошибаетесь. Если Ваш сайт с первого посещения будет понятен чужому пользователю, то ограниченному числу сотрудников подавно. Чтобы не было такого: **Мыши плакали, кололись, но продолжали грызть кактуc**. Ни в коем случае нельзя так поступать, даже с сотрудниками.

> Да и все-таки, так где- же правильней хранить инструкцию в БД или html?

В целях оптимизации, можно и в html. А если по-взрослому: необходимо использовать механизм кэширования блока, либо всей страницы целиком (файловый кэш, memcached, redis,...)

Comment: Да, я согласен, что у меня, каждая страничка документооборота должна быть максимум понятна.  это во-первых.
во-вторых, чтоб даже включить утюг в розетку, предварительно нужно прочесть инструкцию (пора отходить от незнаю каких стандартов и см. guide, это не "game"). Вот хотя бы взять окно обычного MsWord, там сразу не все так понятно (для обычно пользователя ПК), и без "F1", явно не обойтись, но при том он не насыщен "юзабилити". В тоже время он считается одним из наиболее используемым ПО для определенных действий.   
Да, а я всетаки думал, что в БД лучше содержать help (как-то современней)

Comment: > Да, а я всетаки думал, что в БД лучше содержать help

Так я об этом и писал. Результаты запросов, а также данные завёрнутые в шаблон, можно хранить в key-value storages (memcached, redis,...), т.е. БД -> кэш <-> display. Впрочем, для ограниченного числа пользователей, это избыточно, ибо нагрузки никакой. Разве что в академических целях, и если позволяют человеко-часы. Так что без БД никуда.